# Nested templates with tiles

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles, tiles2

I want to have some nested templates with tiles, but without any luck for the moment.

My main template :

```
[...]
<div id=body><tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/></div>
[...]
```

My nested template:

```
[...]
<div id=sub><tiles:insertAttribute name="sub"/></div>
[...]
```

My view definition:

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="mainTemplate" template="/mainTemplate.jspx">
    </definition>
    <definition extends="mainTemplate" name="subTemplate">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/subTemplate.jspx"/>
    </definition>
    <definition extends="mainTemplate" name="myView">
        <put-attribute name="sub" value="blablabla"/>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

What I expected :

```
<div id=body><div id=sub>blablabla</div></div>
```

What I got :

```
<div id=body><div id=sub></div></div>
```

I have seen the [documentation on the tiles website](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/nesting-extending.html) about this subject but I can't make it work :(

Comment: Try to replace blablabla with i.e. /view.jsp and in that file just put the text blablabla.

Comment: Actually, that's already what I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, "subTemplate" and "myView" are two different definitions extending "mainTemplate" both. From what I understand you want the"myView" tile to be nested inside the "subTemplate" tile.

You could try something like this :

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="mainTemplate" template="/mainTemplate.jspx">
    <definition name="subTemplate" extends="mainTemplate">
        <put-attribute name="body">
            <definition template="/subTemplate.jspx">
                <put-attribute name="myView" value="blablabla" />
            </definition>
        </put-attribute>
     </definition>
</tiles-definition>
```

Comment: After more than 2 months of thinking, I confirm, that's the good solution! :D